# Select rows from a pandas dataframe that meets one of two string conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select the rows from a pandas dataframe where the value of CreditCard is either Discover or American Express.  I can get the rows containing these values individually but not with both.

```
# isCorrect = trainDataRetired.loc((['CreditCard'] == 'American Express') or (trainDataRetired['CreditCard'] == 'American Express'))
```

This line is my last attempt but with no success.

This gets me the CreditCard column but with only American Express

```
isCorrect = trainDataRetired['CreditCard'] == 'American Express'
trainDataCorrect = trainDataRetired[isCorrect]
print(trainDataCorrect)
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using the same filter twice. in any case, try to use .loc, like:

```
FILTER_AEX = (trainDataRetired.loc[:,'CreditCard'] == 'American Express')

FILTER_DIS = (trainDataRetired.loc[:,'CreditCard'] == 'Discover')


isCorrect = trainDataRetired.loc[FILTER_AEX | FILTER_DIS, :]
```

and check with

```
isCorrect.loc[:, 'CreditCard'].unique()
```